# OS X Widget Scroll Issue

Tags: macos, wxwidgets, widget

I've built a widget for OS X. It's written in Flash (bah, I know) and is injected into the widget canvas via SWFObject. The problem I'm having is that the Flash has a scroll function and the entire widget is grabable. How can I disable the grab functionality on certain parts of the widget and enable it for others?

I could always transform the scrollbars into clickable ones, but that's not as nice.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's Flash then I'm afraid you didn't really build a widget for OS X.

Comment: That's why I said "bah, I know". There seems to be a culture of widget makers who look down on it. However, these were my development specifications :-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thanks for the help :-p but I answered my own question. Reference resources are quite good with OS X. Somewhat easy to find answers. Have to set appropriate regions:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/Dashboard_Ref/DashboardRegions/DashboardRegions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001339-CH218-BAJIFEBC